# screen in winforms and animation

Tags: winforms, animation

I want to know a name of library (.dll) or class that generates screen like splash screen in wpf?   my application is a winforms(c#) application and i want some animation for it. i need some advices especially how to make a screen with winforms and how to animate my application.  a technology like flash does it exist in .net or another technology exists and it can be used in my case?

Comment: Winforms isn't actually THOUGHT for animation. You can make some crude animations by moving controls and calling the redraw method or draw on the form using a graphics handle...

Comment: I disagree. You can make your animations with Windows Forms if you wish. I have done this numerous times. Just use a blank control or Panel as a canvas, use a timer to move your drawing logic around, and finally call Paint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted a WinForms splash screen sometime ago, I used this as a reference to get me up and running:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5454/A-Pretty-Good-Splash-Screen-in-C

For animations though, like the type you see in modern desktop application splash screens you need to use WPF. You can mix WPF & Winforms.